# Statements possibly equivalent to the $\epsilon{-}N$ definition of limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

> Which of these statements are equivalent to the $\epsilon{-}N$ definition of limit of a sequence?
>
> (a) For every integer $m>0$, there in an integer $N>0$ such that if $n > N$ then 
>   $|a_n - \alpha| < \frac1m$
>
> (b) For each $0<\epsilon <1$, there in an integer $N>0$ such that if $n>N$ then $|a_n - \alpha| < 3\epsilon$
>
> (c) For each $0<\epsilon <1$, there in an integer $N>0$ such that if $n>N$ then $|a_n - \alpha| < \frac{1}{\epsilon}$
>
> (d) For each $\epsilon > 0$, there in an integer $N>0$ such that if $n>N$ then $|a_n - \alpha| < \frac{1}{\epsilon}$
>
> (e) For each $\epsilon > 0$, there in an integer $N>0$ such that if $n>N^2$ then $|a_n - \alpha| < \epsilon$
>
> (f) For each $\epsilon > 0$, there in an integer $N>0$ such that if $n=N+1$ then $|a_n - \alpha| < \epsilon$

Can anyone help me with this? To me all of these seem equivalent to the original
$\epsilon-N$ definition where $\alpha$ is the limit of the sequence. In all the cases we find an $N$ such that for all $n>N$ the statement $|a_n - \alpha| < something$ is true. In (e) and (f) $n>N^2$ and $n = N+1$, respectively, but in both cases it is still greater than $n>N$ so I don't see how this effects the statements.

Comment: No, they are not all equivalent to the original. Think about the original definition again more conceptually perhaps. We want to be able to make $|a_n - a|$ arbitrarily *small* for *all* integers $n$ sufficiently large. Several of these definitions will not allow this.

Comment: Simon S, I think I'm starting to understand it a bit. For (c) we cant make make our "error" arbitrarily small because $0<\epsilon<1$, therefore the minimum value that $1/\epsilon$ can have is $1$. So at most we can find an $N$ such that $|a_n - \alpha| < 1$. For (b) though, this is fine since $3\epsilon$ can be made arbitrarily small. (a) is also wrong then since $1/m$ is a rational number which means that there is always a real number (call it $r$) such that $0<r<1/m$.

Comment: (c) is the only one that I see a problem with

Comment: Option (a) is fine as we can make $1/m$ arbitrarily small; or in other words, given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an integer $m$ such that $0 < 1/m < \epsilon$. Hence option (a) can imply the standard definition. (c) is a problem as you point out. At least one other option is also problematic.

Answer (score -1):

The definition of limit of a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is:
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} a_n = \alpha$$ means:

> for every $\varepsilon > 0$, "no matter how small", $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is, from some point on, within $\varepsilon$ of $\alpha$.

"$x$ is within $\varepsilon$ of $y$" means $|y -x| < e$.

A condition or property is true a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ "from some point on" means that there's an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the property or condition is true about $a_n$ for all $n \ge N$. The $a_i$ can fiddle around for some finite number of $i$, but eventually (starting at $N$) the $a_i$ have to settle down and from that point ($N$) on, for all $n \ge N$, $a_n$ fulfills the condition.

Loosely: to within whatever degree of accuracy or precision we require, the sequence eventually gets that close to $\alpha$ *and stays that close forever after*.

With this in mind, let's run through the statements you list. They're all attempts at expressing that the sequence converges to $\alpha$.

#### Statements (a) - (f)

(a) True (equivalent). For any real $\varepsilon$ there's an integer $m$ with $\frac 1 m \le \varepsilon$.

(b) True. Sufficiently small $\varepsilon$ will be smaller than $1$. We're interested in shrinking the neighborhood around $\alpha$ and ensuring that no matter how small it is, from some point the on the sequence gets into that neighborhood *and stays in that neighborhood*.

(c) False (not equivalent): This says that for any arbitrarily *large* real number $r$ (namely, $1/\varepsilon$), the sequence is eventually within distance $r$ of the limit. But... big deal. This doesn't tell us that the sequence gets *as close as we require to $\alpha$ and stays that close forever*, which is what convergence means.

(d) True. Unlike (c), $\varepsilon$ can be taken *large*, so $1/\varepsilon$ can be arbitrarily *small*.

(e) True: Given $\varepsilon$, there is $M$ (changing variable names) such that from $N = M^2$ on, $a_n$ is within $\varepsilon$ of $\alpha$ for $n > N$.

(f) False: it says "$n = N+1$" which doesn't say anything about the "eventual" behavior of the sequence. (Exercise: find a counterexample.)

Comment: So what I'm thinking so far is that for (c) and (d) as we make the neighborhood around $\alpha$ arbitrarily small (i.e $(\alpha-\epsilon, \alpha + \epsilon)$ ), the statement $|a_n - \alpha| < 1/\epsilon$ means that the distance between the limit and the sequence becomes arbitrarily big.

Comment: For (d) you can make $\varepsilon$ arbitrarily big, thus $1/\varepsilon$ can be arbitrarily small - so yes/true. For (c), the upper bound of $1$ forces $1 < 1/\varepsilon$ so you can't make the reciprocal arbitrarily small.